# How to debug simple udev rules

Tags: usb, mount, udev

I am very new to writing udev rules and the more I read, the more puzzled I get. I am trying to mount the filesystem of a USB stick to a persistent device name. Here is the output of `udevadm info` (cut off after block 3 for better readability):

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1':
KERNEL=="sda1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{SUBSYSTEM}=="block"
ATTR{DEVTYPE}=="partition"
ATTR{PARTN}=="1"
ATTR{MAJOR}=="8"
ATTR{MINOR}=="1"
ATTR{USEC_INITIALIZED}=="1235172438"
ATTR{ID_VENDOR}=="SanDisk"
ATTR{ID_VENDOR_ENC}=="SanDisk\x20"
ATTR{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0781"
ATTR{ID_MODEL}=="Ultra"
ATTR{ID_MODEL_ENC}=="Ultra\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20"
ATTR{ID_MODEL_ID}=="5581"
ATTR{ID_REVISION}=="1.00"
ATTR{ID_SERIAL}=="SanDisk_Ultra_4C530001080716117381-0:0"
ATTR{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="4C530001080716117381"
ATTR{ID_TYPE}=="disk"
ATTR{ID_INSTANCE}=="0:0"
ATTR{ID_BUS}=="usb"
ATTR{ID_USB_INTERFACES}==":080650:"
ATTR{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="00"
ATTR{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usb-storage"
ATTR{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0"
ATTR{ID_PATH_TAG}=="pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0"
ATTR{ID_PART_TABLE_UUID}=="7a6efb82"
ATTR{ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE}=="dos"
ATTR{ID_FS_UUID}=="f3f13dad-53c9-4f1b-b9af-95d504904a9f"
ATTR{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="f3f13dad-53c9-4f1b-b9af-95d504904a9f"
ATTR{ID_FS_VERSION}=="1.0"
ATTR{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ext4"
ATTR{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME}=="dos"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID}=="7a6efb82-01"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE}=="0x83"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER}=="1"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET}=="2048"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE}=="30029824"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK}=="8:0"
ATTR{TAGS}==":systemd:"
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1':
KERNEL=="sda1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{SUBSYSTEM}=="block"
ATTR{DEVTYPE}=="partition"
ATTR{PARTN}=="1"
ATTR{MAJOR}=="8"
ATTR{MINOR}=="1"
ATTR{USEC_INITIALIZED}=="1235172438"
ATTR{ID_VENDOR}=="SanDisk"
ATTR{ID_VENDOR_ENC}=="SanDisk\x20"
ATTR{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0781"
ATTR{ID_MODEL}=="Ultra"
ATTR{ID_MODEL_ENC}=="Ultra\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20"
ATTR{ID_MODEL_ID}=="5581"
ATTR{ID_REVISION}=="1.00"
ATTR{ID_SERIAL}=="SanDisk_Ultra_4C530001080716117381-0:0"
ATTR{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="4C530001080716117381"
ATTR{ID_TYPE}=="disk"
ATTR{ID_INSTANCE}=="0:0"
ATTR{ID_BUS}=="usb"
ATTR{ID_USB_INTERFACES}==":080650:"
ATTR{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="00"
ATTR{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usb-storage"
ATTR{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0"
ATTR{ID_PATH_TAG}=="pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0"
ATTR{ID_PART_TABLE_UUID}=="7a6efb82"
ATTR{ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE}=="dos"
ATTR{ID_FS_UUID}=="f3f13dad-53c9-4f1b-b9af-95d504904a9f"
ATTR{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="f3f13dad-53c9-4f1b-b9af-95d504904a9f"
ATTR{ID_FS_VERSION}=="1.0"
ATTR{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ext4"
ATTR{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME}=="dos"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID}=="7a6efb82-01"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE}=="0x83"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER}=="1"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET}=="2048"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE}=="30029824"
ATTR{ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK}=="8:0"
ATTR{TAGS}==":systemd:"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda':
KERNELS=="sda"
SUBSYSTEMS=="block"
DRIVERS==""
ATTRS{SUBSYSTEM}=="block"
ATTRS{DEVTYPE}=="disk"
ATTRS{MAJOR}=="8"
ATTRS{MINOR}=="0"
ATTRS{USEC_INITIALIZED}=="1235109014"
ATTRS{ID_VENDOR}=="SanDisk"
ATTRS{ID_VENDOR_ENC}=="SanDisk\x20"
ATTRS{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0781"
ATTRS{ID_MODEL}=="Ultra"
ATTRS{ID_MODEL_ENC}=="Ultra\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20"
ATTRS{ID_MODEL_ID}=="5581"
ATTRS{ID_REVISION}=="1.00"
ATTRS{ID_SERIAL}=="SanDisk_Ultra_4C530001080716117381-0:0"
ATTRS{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="4C530001080716117381"
ATTRS{ID_TYPE}=="disk"
ATTRS{ID_INSTANCE}=="0:0"
ATTRS{ID_BUS}=="usb"
ATTRS{ID_USB_INTERFACES}==":080650:"
ATTRS{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="00"
ATTRS{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usb-storage"
ATTRS{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0"
ATTRS{ID_PATH_TAG}=="pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0"
ATTRS{ID_PART_TABLE_UUID}=="7a6efb82"
ATTRS{ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE}=="dos"
ATTRS{TAGS}==":systemd:"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0':
KERNELS=="2:0:0:0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
DRIVERS=="sd"
ATTRS{SUBSYSTEM}=="scsi"
ATTRS{DRIVER}=="sd"
ATTRS{DEVTYPE}=="scsi_device"
ATTRS{MODALIAS}=="scsi:t-0x00"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0':
KERNELS=="2:0:0:0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
DRIVERS=="sd"
ATTRS{SUBSYSTEM}=="scsi"
ATTRS{DRIVER}=="sd"
ATTRS{DEVTYPE}=="scsi_device"
ATTRS{MODALIAS}=="scsi:t-0x00"
```

According to the output I generated the following rule:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0781", ATTR{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="4C530001080716117381", OWNER="ft", SYMLINK+="music"
```

I cannot debug why this is not working. There is no `/dev/music` created, the stick is still mounted to a cryptic mount point.

Comment: Did you run `udevadm control --reload` after adding the rule? Running `udevadm monitor` in a terminal while plugging the USB stick might also help.

Comment: I did run udevadm control --reload and also udevadm monitor. The info of the latter was overwhelming, but nothing stuck out. What exactly would you look for in there in this given case?

Comment: From `monitor` you can see the events that are triggered, like `add` etc. Which Ubuntu version are you using? Running `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb1` gives `E:` for `ID_*` which would translate to `ENV{ID_*}` for the rule instead of `ATTR`. You also can run `udevadm test /sys/class/block/sdb1` to test the rule.

Comment: This is on 18.10. udevadm test /sys/class/block/sda1 reads my rule without complaints, but the stick is still mounted with its UUID

Comment: If you just want to change the mountpoint you do not need a udev rule. Just open *Disks* application while the USB stick is plugged in, select the USB stick and open the *Edit Mount options* menu. From there change the *Mount Point* and replug your device.

Comment: I know that, I want to learn and understand about rules. So I Thought I'd start with an easy one. Goes to show it's not that easy.

Comment: You should look at the output of `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb1`. The rule you provided did work for me after changing `ATTR` to `ENV`.

Comment: It is sda1 and switching ATTR to ENV does nothing. Rule is read, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of wrong type or attribute name. Try one of these rules:

**Using udev environment (ENV)**

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0781", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="4C530001080716117381", OWNER="ft", SYMLINK+="music"
```

**Using ATTRS with kernel naming scheme**

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0781", ATTRS{serial}=="4C530001080716117381", OWNER="ft", SYMLINK+="music"
```

Using ATTRS instead of ATTR checks parent attributes from higher levels, too. Take a look for kernel attributes at: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-4